My animations stopped working
After completing the last animation, I noticed that half of my animations stopped working correctly.

hello could you please share your file (only the armature)?

@moonboots I am a first time user of this site, could you tell me how to send you the file?

link

thanks but these are not the same armature and actions than what you show, maybe the keyframes are for bones that doesn't exist in your armature?

Yeah, thanks, I just saw that the bones have the wrong names on the armature.

The bones of your amature don't have the correct names so they can't be animated by the action.
